# Netty - Clients competing for data?

Tags: java, networking, netty

So, I needed to test a feature in my application which requires me to have two clients open, both of which are connected via localhost. I'm sending all data through the channel, and it seems that the channels are different.

Client One: `[id: 0xd7f05dd1, /127.0.0.1:56571 => /127.0.0.1:5055]`

Client Two: `[id: 0xeb0a36e7, /127.0.0.1:56606 => /127.0.0.1:5055]`

However, when sending information over the network, and having multiple clients open, the clients compete for the data, here's an example:

**Server sending info:**

```
[DEBUG::Packet_02_RegisterRemotePlayer]: Wrote ID: 97271
[DEBUG::Packet_02_RegisterRemotePlayer]: Wrote X: 6.54161
[DEBUG::Packet_02_RegisterRemotePlayer]: Wrote Y: -8.271806
[DEBUG::Packet_02_RegisterRemotePlayer]: Wrote Z: 1.8378098
[DEBUG::Packet_02_RegisterRemotePlayer]: Wrote ROT: 0.0
[DEBUG::Packet_02_RegisterRemotePlayer]: Wrote PRIV: 0
[DEBUG::PacketBuffer]: Packet with an id of 2 was constructed.
[DEBUG::PacketBuffer]: The packet was 28 bytes long.
[DEBUG::PacketBuffer]: The packet type was TCP
```

All of this data is written to a ByteBuf, then sent over the network as a byte[]

This packet was only sent to Client B, containing information about Client A, however Client A and Client B both attack the network to retrieve this data.

All data that was sent above is supposed to be read (in exact order) by client b, however here's the result.

**Client One Read:**

```
[2]Read ID: -1056679599
[2]Read X: 1.8378098
[2]Read Y: 0.0
[2]Read Z: 0.0
```

**Client Two Read:**

```
[2]Read ID: 1087460574
[2]Read X: -8.271806
[2]Read Y: 1.8378098
[2]Read Z: 0.0
[2]Read ROT: 0.0
```

As you can see, the client isn't even completing it's read in either scenario, because the stream is starved, due to both clients attempting to read from it.

When sending data:

```
getChannel().writeAndFlush(buffer.retain());
```

Where all this data is stored in a `ByteBuf`(Netty 4) AKA `ChannelBuffer`(Netty 3)

Debugging shows that we're only sending to **Client Two**, but both clients still try to read it, how can i prevent this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your description. You say you need to `have two clients open`.  I'm assuming you mean you have two client sockets open (controlled by Netty) talking to some server running in a separate process space from your Netty client application? `I'm sending all data through the channel, and it seems that the channels are different.` What channel are you referring to?  So in general if you have two different Netty channels on your client (to your server) they should have the same independence as two sockets would.

Comment: How is your application configuring your pipeline for each channel, and how are your reading the data?  Have you tried only sending to 1 channel from the server, or disabling 1 of the clients from connecting?

Comment: @ScottMitchell - The pipeline for the client is using a standard implementation of `MessageToMessageEncoder` in combination with the `ByteToMessageDecoder` and the `ChannelHandler` is pretty much empty, albeit printing a stack-trace. What I mean by `I'm sending all data through the channel` is that I store the channel of a client when it connects (and authorizes it's connection via a user/pass) for future reference on the server. The server references this channel based on the account the data came from, by getting the channel relative to the `ChannelHandlerContext` passed through the deco...

Comment: ... decode function in the `ByteToMessageDecoder` it then filters through a HashMap<Channel, Account> to find the account relative to this channel, this always works without flaw. (eg: Client A[Tom] sends a message, the server realizes it's tom, etc, etc) - However when sending data out to this channel, both clients attempt to fight over the data, regardless as to which channel i `WriteAndFlush` to, each client being it's own instance of an application.

Comment: I should probably add that if I connect three, or four clients to the server, then they **ALL** will compete for the data, I know this isn't a problem with the channel I'm sending over, because I created a small application using `OIO Sockets` and it worked just fine. --- **each client being it's own instance of an application.**

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot going on here. Can you provide code for your client channel creation and channel pipeline initialization? It would be preferable to deal with a minimal set of code that demonstrates the issues. You may want to pull our this portion of the code (creating multiple independent client channels) and isolate it so you can get it working, and then integrate it back in with your application logic. The more minimal you can make your demonstration code the more likely you will be to get help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66079/discussion-between-christian-tucker-and-scott-mitchell).